# What are database escape() and quote() used for?

Tags: joomla

I looked at some joomla components and there are functions like

```
$db->escape()
$db->quote()
```

What are they used for ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thes escape function is used to escape bad characters in order to protect against SQL injection.

The quote* functions are used to quote strings, because different database dialects have different quoting characters.

So depending on the database system you use, Joomla will choose the appropriate quoting characters.

Comment: Might be helpful http://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines#Constructing_SQL_queries

Comment: wonder how the $db->quote(null) will return, is it NULL or an empty string?